# org-agenda-write doesn't respect org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda

Running a fresh Emacs session with `emacs -Q`, I evaluated the following:

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/index.org"))
(setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)
```

where `~/index.org` simply contains:

```
* Project heading
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ORDERED:  t
  :END:
** TODO First subheading
** TODO Second subheading
```

When I call `(org-agenda nil "t")` to display the available TODOs, it correctly displays only "First subheading." However, if I then export that buffer with `org-agenda-write`, then the resulting file contains both "First subheading" and "Second subheading."

What is going on here, and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The blocked entries are present in the agenda. It's just that they're invisible.

A work-around would be to not set blocked tasks to `invisible`. Instead, create an `org-agenda-custom-command` with a non-standard skip-function that actually filters out blocked entries:

```
("s" "Describe command here" todo "TODO"
 ((org-agenda-skip-function
  (function my-org-agenda-skip-blocked))))
```

and

```
(defun my-org-agenda-skip-blocked ()
  "Skip blocked entries"
  (let ((heading-end (save-excursion (outline-next-heading))))
    (if (org-entry-blocked-p)
        heading-end
        nil)))
```